# Buttons's images from url -failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, url

I have an URL which contain a json format.

```
{
      "name":"RAI Radiodue",
      "cat":"Adult Contemporary",
      "img":"http://www.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/images/ico_radio2.jpg",
      "url":"http://www.listenlive.eu/rai2.m3u"
   },
   {
      "name":"RAI Radiotre",
      "cat":"Classical/Culture",
      "img":"http://www.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/images/ico_radio3.jpg",
      "url":"http://www.listenlive.eu/rai3.m3u"
   }........etc
```

I'm trying to display many radio button using this code:

```
    for (int i = 0;  i<[namesArray count]; i++) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [pictureUrl objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];



        UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        int xxx = i%3;
        int yyy = i/3.0f;
        [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(35+95*xxx, 15+100*yyy, 60, 60)];
        [bt setBackgroundImage:subview forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        bt.tag = 200+i;
        bt.selected = NO;
        [bt.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
        [bt.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [bt.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
        [bt.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
        [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(Play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [mainscroll addSubview:bt];
}
```

and adding for each button an image from pictureUrl which is populated , but when I want to go to this view controller So I get this output in my console:

```
2014-12-18 17:32:40.763 TV[3128:935103] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2014-12-18 17:32:46.041 TV[3128:935134] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: If you log url (after the first line in your loop), does it give you the correct urls? Also, in the line where you use setBackgroundImage:forState:, you're passing a UIImageView instead of a UIImage which is incorrect.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [pictureUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
 = it returns the correct urls , but  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

This line block the main thread, the main thread does wait data dowloading before run this lines :

```
UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

You must ran downloading data in other thread and set your image when data are downloaded.

Comment: I used dispatch_async . In first block i get data from url and in the second i set the image . Now my problem is : the new view controller is present but the app is like i dont have network connection .

Comment: did you try to use something like asyncImageView ? : https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

And also try to make just one button with your data ?

Answer (score 0):

There either must be something wrong with the pictureUrl array, or you didn't have an internet connection when you ran the code. When I run you code, passing in the 2 strings you show in your post, the code works fine,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *stringsArray = @[@"http://www.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/images/ico_radio2.jpg", @"http://www.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/images/ico_radio3.jpg"];
    [self downloadImagesFromNamesArray:stringsArray];

}

-(void)downloadImagesFromNamesArray:(NSArray *) namesArray {
    for (int i = 0;  i<[namesArray count]; i++) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [namesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        int xxx = i%3;
        int yyy = i/3.0f;
        [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(35+95*xxx, 15+100*yyy, 60, 60)];
        [bt setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        bt.tag = 200+i;
        bt.selected = NO;
        [bt.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
        [bt.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [bt.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
        [bt.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
        [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(Play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.mainscroll addSubview:bt];
    }
}
```

Also notice that I fixed the problem where you were trying to set the background image of the button using an image view instead of an image.

A better way to do the download would be to use an asynchronous download method like sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: (or NSURLSession methods). If you do this, you will get some error handling, and the app will not be blocked while the download happens. When doing it this way, you can't use a loop, but instead, you should download the next image from the completion block of the asynchronous method.

```
-(void) downloadImagesFromNamesArray:(NSArray *) imageURLStrings {
    static int count = 0;
    NSString *urlString = imageURLStrings[count];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"%@", connectionError);
            count ++;
            if (count < imageURLStrings.count) {
                [self downloadImagesFromNamesArray:imageURLStrings];
            }
        }else{
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (img) {
                UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                int xxx = count%3;
                int yyy = count/3.0f;
                [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(35+95*xxx, 15+100*yyy, 60, 60)];
                [bt setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                bt.tag = 200+ count;
                bt.selected = NO;
                [bt.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
                [bt.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
                [bt.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
                [bt.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
                [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(Play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [self.mainscroll addSubview:bt];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Data was received but no image was created from the data");
            }

            count ++;
            if (count < imageURLStrings.count) {
                [self downloadImagesFromNamesArray:imageURLStrings];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: For the firts option: the same problem and for second when it's to the line 5 it's go out from the block.